Pointwise spanning property for orthonormal basis of vector-valued $L^2$
Consider $H=L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e.\ the space of squared integrable measurable functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\Omega$ a nice bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (smooth boundary etc, or if you like could also be a smooth manifold). The case I am interested in is actually $\Omega=\mathbb{T}^d$. Say I have an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B:=(f_i)_i$ of $H$ consisting of smooth functions (say $C^\infty$ as smooth as you like). I want to solve the following:

Problem. Prove or disprove there exists a finite set of open balls $(U_k)_{k=1}^N$ covering $\Omega$ and  sets $(\mathcal F_k)_{k=1}^N$ consisting of finitely many functions in $\mathcal B$ for which the set $\{f(x)\colon f\in \mathcal F_k\}$ spans $\mathbb{R^n}$ for almost every $x\in U_k$.

It is a a.e. pointwise spanning property for the target space.
Some thoughts. What I have tried is to consider determinants of a collection of $n$ functions from $(f_i)_i$ and  argue by compactness or the sort (also using continuity of the orthonormal basis). This does not seem to work because one needs to know that there is a collection of $n$ functions at each point in $\Omega$ such that the determinant is non-zero. If I know that, then I know the existence of an open ball by continuity and then argue by compactness.
I think a fun way of proving by Baire Category Theorem might be lurking somewhere. I can't see it though.
Context. Also if it helps, the orthonormal basis is obtained from a self-adjoint nice differential operator. Let me also add more context, this question arised in knowing what the regularity of a matrix valued function $A$ is, when one knows that $Af$ is smooth for each $f\in\mathcal B$. If we solve the problem then the hope is to argue that each component of $A$ is smooth. On the other hand the last might require an operation that breaks down regularity. Hence, I'm not even sure my original problem can be solved this way. Regardless the problem posed above is interesting regardless.
Any ideas, hints or counterexamples are appreciated.

''functions that span $\mathbb R^n$'' does not make too much sense. Can you please write, what you are interested in ?

@daw apologies for the sloppiness. I made it more precise, is it clear now?

There's something called smooth partitions of unity, maybe that's of interest to you?

@Se7venn That would be interesting, if I had the freedom in choosing the orthonormal basis, right? In here the basis is given
